# Get the Server Name from Connection string Defined in App.config File?

Tags: c#, connection-string

I want to get IP Adress of ConnectionString's serverName from my app.config file and then ping it.
Actually i want ping my server before running my application.
how do i do this?
my ConnectionString

```
<"name="ConnectionString"
 connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.5;
                   Initial Catalog=CheckPass2;
                   User ID=User;
                   Password=myPassword" />
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).  More often then not other SO users would like to see that you attempted it yourself as SO wasn't designed as a *give me teh code* website.

Comment: Have you put IPAddress in the `servername` in your `App.config`?

Comment: yes, my connectionstring is like this :name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.5;Initial Catalog=CheckPass2;User ID=User;Password=myPassword"

Comment: Add your connection String in question...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> How do I do this?

You can get the server address using [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.datasource.aspx).The `DataSource` property of this class can be used for this as below:

```
// Retrieve the ConnectionString from App.config 
string connectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectString);
// Retrieve the DataSource property.    
string IPAddress = builder.DataSource;
```

This `DataSource` property corresponds to the following keys within the connection string.

- Data Source
- server
- address
- addr and
- network address

Regardless of which of these values has been supplied within the supplied connection string, the connection string created by the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` will use the well-known `"Data Source"` key.

Comment: Just for clarity, this will get the name of the data source. The user can type an IP address OR the name of the computer.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that 'Data Source" will also include any port number, if specified. In this format: 'server, 1234'.

Comment: ... *and* it will also include the instance name, if the SQL Server instance has a named instance...